# JetBrains (PyCharm, WebStorm, etc.) - Change Shift-Shift Search Everywhere to default Files tab

Tags: pycharm, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is it possible to set the default tab for Search Everywhere when opened with <kbd>Shift + Shift</kbd>?

I'd like to start in the "Files" tab not the "All" tab.

Comment: This can be done, but PyCharm doesn't allow setting the `Shift+Shift` shortcut.  So if you want the functionality you have to use a different shortcut.

Comment: **Navigate > File** will open **Search Everywhere** with **Files** tab focused